# Why is the picture changed by opencv is unclear in iOS program?

Tags: ios, opencv

I use the opencv in iOS:

```
UIImage* original_Img = [UIImage imageNamed:IMG_NAME];
UIImageToMat(original_Img, _cvImage, true);
UIImage* rImage = MatToUIImage(_cvImage);
[self.personView setImage:rImage];
```

[image contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MG7f.jpg)

why is the picture unclear？